# Classic ASP SQL Statement fails on type provider error

Tags: sql, asp-classic, type-mismatch

I keep getting the following error:

Provider error '80020005'
Type mismatch.
/core/Includes/CommonDBRoutines.asp, line 872

When I try to run the following SQL Statement:

```
Dim rsIsTaskComplete
Redim sqlParams(0)                 
SQL="SELECT isTaskCompleted FROM Tasks" & _
"WHERE TaskID='10' AND isTaskCompleted=1;"
Set rsIsTaskComplete= ExecuteReader(esceddb, SQL, sqlParams)
If Not rsIsTaskComplete.EOF Then
    strIsTaskComplete="True"
Else
    strIsTaskComplete="False"
End if
```

Other similar statements located just before and after it work perfectly. Just this one seems to fail. I don't know why?

Comment: What happens if you use `WHERE TaskID=10` rather than `WHERE TaskID='10'?`

Comment: Your SQL needs a space between Tasks and WHERE. Do a Response.write SQL and confirm that.